# iOS library's angle bracket imports failing

Tags: xcode, import, linker

I am building an iOS project and I want to link in a static library from OpenSceneGraph. Right now, I have imported the header files into the project.

In my ViewController, I have the statement:

```
#import "osg/Geode"
```

and this does not give an error.

(I initially tried

```
#import <osg/Geode>
```

but Xcode told me I needed to use quotes instead.)

However, when I try to compile the project, Xcode runs into an issue when it does import osg/Geode. That file includes the line

```
#import <osg/Node>
```

When Xcode tries to compile, it imports "osg/Geode", and then it tries to import , but the angle brackets don't work there either, so it fails.

How can I fix this issue? Thank you!

[image: My code]
[image: OSG Code]

### Update

As per Reck Hou's suggestion, I edited my "Header Search Paths" in build settings.

```
"$(SRCROOT)"      - recursive
```

Now, when I try to compile, I get errors coming from the header files. Ex. "Unknown type name 'namespace'", "Expected ';' after top level declarator". I am also getting the error "'ostream' fiel not found".
[image: Other errors]
[image: Ostream error]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Into your project setting then find your building target->`build settings`.

Find `Header search paths` then add your header path into it.

For example:

> "$(SRCROOT)/[your header path]"

Be advice, add parent directory path takes no effect.

e.g. You should add static library into `Build Phases`->`Link Binary With Libraries` to prevent link error.

Comment: I did this and got errors. Please see my updated original post. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You should add header path which includes 'ostream' as well.

Comment: Where would I find that header? I am using Mac OS X 10.8.3.

Comment: Ostream is a c++ standard library, which version of compiler and c++ standard are you using now? You can get these info from project setting as well.

Comment: Are you using the newest version of OSG?

Comment: Hmm. It seems strange that Xcode would have trouble finding part of the C++ Standard Library. Is that a common thing that throws errors? I am worried something may be wrong with my installation of Xcode...  

Yes, I am using OSG 3.0.1. 
@ReckHou
compiler: Apple LLVM compiler 4.2  
C language dialect: GNU99 [-std=gnu99]   
C++ language dialect: GNU++11 [-std=gnu++11]  
C++ Standard Library: libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)

Comment: Try to import <ostream> in your own code to see if this error still exists, also try to modify these language settings to see whether it works or not.

Comment: Importing <ostream> in my own code works without throwing an error.  
I tried all permutations of the language settings without success.  
I also renamed my .m files to .mm files so that it would compile with C++.  
Thank you very much for your help - I really need to figure this out today.

Answer (score 1):

'namespace' is not a valid Objective-C keyword.
What extension is ScopedLock file? Is it .mm? 
You need to tell xCode to compile it as C++.

To do that go to you Project Settings, choose the Target -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM compiler X.X - Language -> Compile Sources As. Set it to Objective-C++ which allows mixture of Objective-C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're going to need to edit the header search paths in your build settings.